# Should the Oj lobe of a Lafortune shader cause the light to be displaced?

Tags: shaders, webgl

I implemented the Lafortune shader in WebGL, and my biggest concern is about this formula:

[image]

**Explanation**

Kd/Ks is the material diffuse/specular color, ρd/ρs is the light diffuse/specular component, m is the number of lobes (in my shader I always use a single lobe), o is the viewer direction (from the surface point), i is the light direction, Oj is the lobe and ej is the shininess factor.
Full reference is here: [A survey of shading models for real-time rendering](http://www.karsten-schwenk.de/downloads/a_survey_of_shading_models.pdf), at page 28.

**Question**

The problem comes with the Oj lobe. I realized that as I change the value of Oj, the light gets displaced from it's original position, for example that's what I get with Oj= (-1,-1,1):

[image]

And that's what I get with Oj=(0,0,1):

[image]

Is that behavior normal? Should the light get displaced according to the value of Oj?

Comment: Lafortune's BRDF model is described in detail (including example source code) in [this GPU Gems article](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch18.html).

Comment: I also added my reference editing the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, absolutely, **it is expected** that somehow the light appears to be at a different place if you change the main lobe’s properties without considering what it means physically.

The lobes describe, for a given incident light direction, in which directions light is going to be re-emitted. Here are a few examples of possible lobes: a perfect specular reflection lobe (for the Phong model), an off-specular lobe, and a retroreflection lobe (as is the case for catadioptric surfaces).

[image: lobes]

You are probably familiar with the [specular highlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_highlight). When the surface is very shiny, it is the area around which the most re-emitted light reaches the viewer’s eye. This happens where the light direction and the viewer direction are exactly reflected (*i.e.* the view vector is close to the **R** vector above).

In the case of retroreflection there is a highlight, too, but that highlight is located where the light and viewer direction are close to each other (*i.e.* the view vector is close to the **L** vector).

Here is an example of highlighted areas in those two different cases:

[image: highlights]

As you can see, depending on the lobe, and even if the light does not move, the highlights can be at very different locations.

In your specific case, you chose `Oj = [0,0,1]`. It means that whatever the direction of the incident light, the most light will always be re-emitted along the surface’s normal. In other words, the highlight will be located **where the view vector is facing the surface normal**. And this is precisely what your second screenshot shows.